# npx create-react-app my-app giving me the following error after installing new version of NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I installed a new version of NodeJS after that I'm trying to create-react-app and on running the command `npx create-react-app my-app` is giving me the following error:

```
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\ALL ABOUT React\Jonas Projects\Jonass Project Practice\myproject> npm -v          
8.1.0
PS E:\ALL ABOUT React\Jonas Projects\Jonass Project Practice\myproject> node -v
    v16.13.0
PS E:\ALL ABOUT React\Jonas Projects\Jonass Project Practice\myproject> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code EPERM  
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\724ab6af
npm ERR! errno EPERM
npm ERR! FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\724ab6af'
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:162:15
npm ERR!     at async C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:106:12
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:94:17)      
npm ERR!  FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app: EPERM: 
    operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\724ab6af'
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:162:15
npm ERR!     at async C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:106:12
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:94:17) {    
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   errno: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Firstname~1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\724ab6af',
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
PS E:\ALL ABOUT React\Jonas Projects\Jonass Project Practice\myproject>
```

Comment: Try opening the shell as admin?

Comment: Yes already tried

Comment: Does it work on C: ?

Comment: What does it  means on C , I am new to react that's why  have not enough knowledge, trying to figure it from last 3 days but nothing could help me , and one other thing , my old projects are running well but npx create-react-app my- app giving the error

Comment: Sorry, I mean on `C:` drive, you try to run it on `E:` I guess this is not your main drive isn't it?

Comment: I think your E: drive might need permission to load the stuff from C:

Comment: I solved through cmd , first I created folder with cmd ,then I run npx create-react-app my-app it created created react app now I can use in VS Code ,but Idk why it has problem when I try to do with terminal .

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`npx create-react-app my-app`

instead of:

`npx-create-react-app my-app`

project name should not be capitalize or such symbol like dash(-)